# Consulta no funciona combinando dos tablas en sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito en esta expresion:

```
SELECT column_name, 
nullable, 
data_type 
FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name = 'CLIENTE';
```

Donde se muestra el nombre, si puede estar vacia, y el tipo de dato de las columnas de la tabla cliente, añadir el tipo de clave que es cada una de las columnas.

He hecho esto a continaución, pero se me repiten las columnas y ya he probado con DISTINCT y sigue apareciendo lo mismo, de que forma hago que se combinen las tablas y no me aparezcan repetidos?

Esta es mi sentencia hasta ahora:

```
SELECT CC.column_name, 
CC.nullable, 
CC.data_type, 
C.constraint_type 
FROM user_constraints C, 
user_tab_columns CC
WHERE CC.table_name = 'CLIENTE' 
AND C.table_name = 'CLIENTE';
```

Os dejo también el enunciado del ejercicio, por si no me llego a explicar bien:

```
-- Escribe una consulta utilizando la vista USER_TAB_COLUMNS que devuelva las mismas columnas que DESCRIBE para la tabla
-- CLIENTE.

SELECT column_name, 
nullable, 
data_type 
FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name = 'CLIENTE';

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Mejora la consulta anterior, añadiendo una columna que indique si un atributo forma parte de la clave primaria o no.
```

Añado la respuesta que me ha pasado un compañero, pero es muy diferente a la mia y necesitaria una explicación o una respuesta más cercana a mi expresión.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, nullable
    FROM user_tab_columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'CLIENTE' AND column_name IN(
        SELECT CC.column_name
        FROM user_cons_columns CC, user_constraints C
        WHERE CC.constraint_name = C.constraint_name AND C.constraint_type='P' AND CC.table_name='CLIENTE'
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás haciendo mal el *join*. Hay que hacerlo por los dos campos, el nombre de la tabla **y el nombre de la columna**.

Puede hacerse como tú lo estás haciendo:

```
select cc.column_name, 
cc.nullable, 
cc.data_type, 
c.constraint_type
from user_constraints c, 
user_tab_columns cc
where c.table_name = cc.table_name
and c.column_name = cc.column_name
and c.table_name = 'CLIENTE';
```

O con *joins*:

```
select cc.column_name, 
cc.nullable, 
cc.data_type, 
c.constraint_type
from user_constraints c
inner join user_tab_columns cc
on  c.table_name = cc.table_name
and c.column_name = cc.column_name
where c.table_name = 'CLIENTE';
```

A mí me gusta más con joins, me parece que al motor de base de datos se le da
una instrucción más clara sobre cómo optimizar la columna, pero nunca he
visto diferencias apreciables.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me ha servido de mucho